# Change DHCP discover frequecy on CISCO?

Tags: cisco, dhcp

Is it possible to change the frequency that a CISCO router sends a DHCP discover packet? Or is there a way to poke it and make it request one?

Answer (score 0):

why on earth would you have a router using DHCP for addressing?

the frequency will depend on the lease its already obtained from the DHCP server.

powercycling should also force it to recheck, as will configuring the interface statically and then switching back to DHCP.

Comment: Changing the lease time would change the frequency that it has to renew its address, but not the frequency with which it tries to discover an address.
I'm using a backup connection that give a DHCP address, and when the router first switches on the backup connection, it also sends a DHCP discover, but the other side isn't ready for it yet - about a second later, the other side has DHCP up and running, but then the CISCO router takes quite a while to send another discover message.

Comment: That's screwed. Or your explanation is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the dhcp discover, but you can set the lease time on the dhcp client :

`router(config-if)#ip dhcp client lease <days> [hours] [minutes]`

It should at lease send a dhcp renew when the lease expires.

To force a renew :

`router#renew dhcp <interface>`